# Change status in ajax on selectbox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, php-5.3

I have a question, So ,this code work fine only for the first select box and I dont understand why. For first select box update on database work fine but If I tried to change the statut for the second select box the status remain unchanged. Can you help me? Sorry for my english

My view :

`{% for gift in aFilterGifts %}`

```
<form action="" id="updateStatus" method="post">
    <select id="statusSelect"
            name="{{ gift.id }}"
            class="form-control"
            onChange="updateCadeauStatus({{ gift.id }})">
            {% for key,statut in form_logistique.statut.choices %}
                <option value="{{ key }}"
                    {% if gift.etat == key %}selected="selected"{% endif %}>
                    {{ statut }}
                 </option>
            {% endfor %}
   </select>
</form>
{% endfor %}

 <script>
    function updateCadeauStatus(id) {
        var id = id;
        var selectedName = $("#statusSelect option:selected").val();
        var url_deploy = 'http:localhost/updateStatus'
        console.log(id);
        console.log(selectedName);
        $.ajax({
            url: url_deploy,
            type: "POST",
            async: true,
            data: { id_cadeau:id, id_status:selectedName}
        });
    }
</script>
```

The controller :

```
public function updateStatus(){
    $iGiftId    = $_POST['id_cadeau'];
    $iNewStatus = $_POST['id_status'];
    $bUpdate = $this->updateStatusByGiftId($iGiftId, $iNewStatus);

}
```

The model :

```
public static function updateStatusByGiftId($iGiftId, $iStatusId){
    $request = sprintf( ' UPDATE `%s` set etat = %d WHERE id_instant_gagnant = %d ', $table, $iStatusId, $iGiftId);

    return Mysqli::query($request, $database);
}
```

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your select boxes do have the same id `id="statusSelect"`.
That's not valid HTML.
One solution would be to append the gift id to the id tag to create unique ids:

```
{% for gift in aFilterGifts %}
    <form action="" id="updateStatus{{ gift.id }}" method="post">
        <select id="statusSelect{{ gift.id }}"
                name="{{ gift.id }}"
...
```

and for the script:

```
<script>
    function updateCadeauStatus(id) {
        var id = id,
            selectedName = $("#statusSelect" + id + " option:selected").val(),
            url_deploy = 'http:localhost/updateStatus';

        console.log(id);
...
```